# Correct Hashing Algorithm/Function

Tags: hash, language-agnostic, passwords

Are there any secure hashing algorithms/functions that give all the letters and numbers, and not just 0-9,a-f.

So the output could contain: 0-9, a-z, A-Z and even some symbols.

Comment: Is there a reason you're looking to find an algorithm, rather than some built-in types in whatever language you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your favorite hashing algorithm/function and convert the output to base64.  A mechanism to do that in Java is here: [how to convert hex to base64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372268/how-to-convert-hex-to-base64).

Note that the hash value will still be the same, but the presentation will be different.  If there's a reason you want to use a fuller symbol set, perhaps you could edit your question.

Comment: This prompted me to research base 64, and it exactly suits my needs.

Comment: If you are thinking of designing your own hash algorithm, and you don't have a Ph.D. in math and ten years' experience in cryptography, please read this: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own

Answer (score 2):

Any hashing algorithm, really.

Hexadecimal is just a common representation for them. Look at [this code snippet](http://codepad.org/QrXLaR65) (using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), because you didn't tag a programming language):

```perl
use Digest::MD5 qw/md5 md5_hex/;
use MIME::Base64;

my $str = 'Foobar';

# Hexadecimal representation
print md5_hex($str),"\n";

# Base64 encoded representation
print encode_base64(md5($str));
```

Output:

```
89d5739baabbbe65be35cbe61c88e06d
idVzm6q7vmW+NcvmHIjgbQ==
```

The first output is the hexadecimal representation of the MD5 digest of the string; the second is the Base64 encoded representation of the raw digest.

This would work with any digesting algorithm. It does not, however, affect how secure the underlying algorithm *actually* is.