# Hexadecimal string to Base64 string in Java for android

Tags: java, android, base64, hex

I am struggling to convert a hex string to base64 string in java. I have already tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372268/how-to-convert-hex-to-base64) but `Hex.decodeHex` is showing errors.

```
    byte[] decodedHex;
    byte[] encodedHexB64;

    try {
      decodedHex = Hex.decodeHex("1234567890123458");
      encodedHexB64 = Base64.encodeBase64(decodedHex);
      System.out.println("FINAL ENCODED STRING -> "+encodedHexB64.toString());
     .
     ..}
```

Throws below error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method decodeHex(Ljava/lang/String;)[B in class Lorg/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex; or its super classes (declaration of 'org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex' appears in /system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar)
```

I also tried to convert it to byte array and then convert to base64 string but that is also not working for me.

```
byte[] decodedHex;
byte[] encodedHexB64;
try {
  decodedHex = hexStringToByteArray(finalString); // finalString = 1234567890123458
  encodedHexB64 = Base64.encodeBase64(decodedHex);
  System.out.println("FINAL ENCODED STRING -> "+encodedHexB64.toString()); 
  .
  ..}

  // Desired output = EjRWeJASNFg= 
  // But actual output is FINAL ENCODED STRING -> [B@173943
```

[checking the same input here gives the desired output](https://base64.guru/converter/encode/hex)

I have also tried to use Rhino to use javascript environment to get this value from javascript functions but that is also not working for me. There must be some way in java to get this. your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using the `java.util.Base64` or some other imported class?

Comment: Used this one as well which has .getEncoder method. This works fine but add two extra zeros in the finalString variable automatically and then calculates base64 string.

Comment: Apache commons Base64 is throwing the Hex.decodeHex issue i have shown in the question

Comment: Why are the zeros a problem? Base64.getDecoder should perfectly convert it back to the original when needed.

Comment: Hex.decodeHex() expects an argument of type char[], not byte[].